# Is it correct to manually copy header .hpp files into my project_root/boost library?

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I was reading the documentation and found it quite vague:

> To compile anything in Boost, you need a directory containing the boost/ subdirectory in your #include path.
>
> Since all of Boost's header files have the .hpp extension, and live in
>   the boost/ subdirectory of the boost root, your Boost #include
>   directives will look like:

```
#include <boost/whatever.hpp>
```

> or

```
#include "boost/whatever.hpp"
```

> depending on your preference regarding the use of angle bracket
>   includes.

Am I supposed to always create a subdirectory named "boost" in my project root and then manually copy each .hpp file I need from my boost installation/header directory into the project_root/boost directory?

I could also see telling Eclipse to automatically scan my boost root installation/include directory for the headers, thus avoiding the manual copy.  Also, I could see making a soft link to the boost root installation/include directory into the project boost folder so as to include everything without having to make a single manual copy.

One difference I see is ***including the boost header files in my projects*** versus ***not including them in my project and referring to them externally***

I am not sure which of these strategies is right.  Which is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct option for smallish development projects is probably the one you suggest here:

"I could also see telling Eclipse to automatically scan my boost root installation/include directory for the headers, thus avoiding the manual copy." (Specifically, adding your boost installation's include directory to your compiler/Eclipse search path.)

That is what the boost documentation means by having a directory containing boost/ in your #include path.

For small individual projects, you don't really want to be messing around creating hand-built links to boost includes for each project if your boost installation rarely changes, unless that's a part of your broader build strategy across projects.  I've worked in organisations where this **is**  done for good reasons, basically to enable you to set up different build instances pointing at different versions of boost (or other third party libraries) by just switching some symbolic links, rather than messing around with the make dependencies and paths.

So setting up sym links to boost's include, lib, etc. inside your project might be an option if you want that level of flexibility.

However, manually copying the boost header files into your project each time is not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual,- and certainly not good practice-, to copy library headers to your projects, and it's not necessary at all.
Use the `-I` option to tell the compiler which additional pathes to search for include files.
Concerning Eclipse CDT, you can add the additional include pathes using the C++-Build Options of your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to them externally.

Copying library files into application projects is nothing but copy-n-pasting code at a higher level. Don't do it. It typically leads to an extremely unstructured software architecture. You should even take the opposite direction: modularise your project's own code to create *your own internal libraries*, which your project then treats exactly like Boost libraries or the standard library. This is what your application project's files should look like:

```
#include <your_own_library/whatever.h>
#include <boost/whatever.hpp>
#include <string>

class ApplicationSpecificClass
{
 // ...
};
```

Thinking in terms of libraries and APIs will improve your software-engineering skills significantly. It only requires that you learn more about your build environment and the options featured by your compiler and linker (both to create libraries and to use them). Learning how to use Boost libraries is a **good start**, because most of them are header-only libraries, which makes everything easier.